# Background img repeat x and Y

Tags: css, background-image, repeat

I was trying to work with background image property. I was really confused with repeat x and y. I have tried to figure out what it does, and I found online things I found not good enough. I have created two columns, and the left column would get 63% and the right column 37%(approximate). I used background image with 3000px width and 160 height, and used two different colors for the two columns. That is, after 1890px or 63% the color changes.

I am using my laptop with 1350px wide screen. I kept changing the percentage of repeat-y and see what is it is doing. I still can't figure out, what happening. This is what I understood, and if I am wrong please give me more simpler explanation. For me, if I set repeat y 44%, then it is taking 44% of the current container, let say Z PX, and set the background image by starting from z PX to the end of image, in my case to 3000px, and repeat the process vertically. I hope I am clear. Am I correct? Please, let me know what you think or explain to me on your own ways. Thanks!

```
#page{

        background:url("bg.jpg") repeat-y 63%;

    }
    .clear{
       clear:both;
    }
    div.left{
        width:63.11111111%;
        float:left;



    }
    div.right{
        float:right;
        width:36%;

    }

 }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">

        <div class="left">
            this is left column
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            this is right column
        </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>   
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Comment: put a code online: try http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

The background-repeat property and the background-position property are two different things. The background-repeat property sets if or how a background image will be repeated; default, a background-image is repeated both vertically (= repeat-y) and horizontally (= repeat-x).

In your example the image will be vertically repeated; but the div's your are using don't show much about it, because the image is much bigger than your div's . **I suggest you try it with a smaller image, e.g. 25x25px and put some text (e.g. lorem ipsum) in  or give this a height of 200 px, and play with the values again.**

The background-position property sets the starting position of a background image; the first value is the horizontal position and the second value is the vertical.

In your example the percentage describes the point off the image to start from, on the horizontal axis.

If you only specify one keyword, like you did, the other value for the vertical axis will be "center". So your image will be viewable from the middle, on the vertical axis.

**Try out my suggestion!** If it does not seem to be working, I'll put an example online. Let me know.

PS: There are no colors specified for the columns.

Comment: May be I asked it wrongly. I was looking for different response. I was reading cascading style sheets the definitive guide by Meyer. There is one point, on page 261, "percentage values apply to both the element and the origin image". So when I say 63%, then 63% of 3000px wide image that is at 1890px of the image, and 63% to the right (horizontal) of the container window are aligned together

Comment: The background-position is what you specify with those percentages, this will not influence the container/window. The percentage will (indeed) only determine at which point (your 1890px) the image starts aligning with his container. (I think you understand it but it seems hard to explain.)